# MUI Autocomplete - Make all options selected by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've be using this example to try and get the values in the autocomplete drop down to be automatically selected by default. I'm looking to get all the values to be selected when the page is loaded. Does anyone know how to do this?

Sandbox code :
https://codesandbox.io/s/s26gz?file=/demo.js:504-523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `defaultValue` props to Autocomplete like this

```
  <Autocomplete
    options={options}
    value={value}
    defaultValue={top100Films}
    ...
  />
```

Comment: this worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can control the `value` of the `Autocomplete` by overriding the `value`/`onChange` props and use `useState` to set the initially selected options:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options);

return (
  <Autocomplete
    options={options}
    value={value}
    onChange={(e, v) => setValue(v)}
    {...}
  />
);
```

Or if you're using [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) mode, simply pass a `defaultValue`:

```
<Autocomplete
  defaultValue={options}
  {...}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]